# Need a monitoring script to compare the disk space of the build folders at two different NFS locations to identify the time

Tags: python, nfs, diskspace

There are two different locations:
A) /nfs/appdata/6500_build : This is located at India Machine(linux)
B)/nfs/appdata/bamboo_6500_dest : This is located at Ottawa Machine(linux)

Builds are simultaneously building at (A) and are copying at (B).
I need a script which can monitor the disk space of the build folders being made at both locations and to identify the time

Comment: have you tried ```df``` command? you can compare the result by parsing its output

Comment: You can look at a monitoring system such as [nagios](https://www.nagios.org/).